# Best way to check for null values using *ngFor in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm showing some records coming from an `api` and some of the results are null and I would like to show a different value in case the response values are null. How would be the best way to do it?

Below is my code:

Component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {PerformancesService} from '../../services/performances.service';
import {Performance} from '../../common/performance';

@Component({
    selector: 'performances',
    templateUrl: './app/components/performances/performances.component.html'
})

export class PerformancesComponent implements OnInit{
    performances: Performance[];

    constructor(private _service : PerformancesService){

    }

    getFunds(){
        this._service.getData().then(
            performances => this.performances = performances
        )
    }

    ngOnInit(){ 
        this.getFunds();
    }
}
```

template:

```
<h2>Performance</h2>

<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Fund Id</th>
          <th>Country Id</th>
          <th>1Mth</th>
          <th>3Mth</th>
          <th>YTD</th>
          <th>1Yr</th>
          <th>3Yrs</th>
          <th>5Yrs</th>
          <th>10Yrs</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let performance of performances">
        <td>{{performance.id}}</td>
        <td>{{performance.country_id}}</td>
        <td>{{performance.OneMonthBack}}</td>
        <td>{{performance.ThreeMonthsBack}}</td>
        <td>{{performance.YearToDate}}</td>
        <td>{{performance.OneYearBack}}</td>
        <td>{{performance.ThreeYearsBack}}</td>
        <td>{{performance.FiveYearsBack}}</td>
        <td>{{performance.TenYearsBack}}</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I don't know if I could do it in the template or I should check each value in my component. Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: I have created a method `getDefaultIfNull` that takes any value as argument and returns actual value if not null and returns `"-"` if null. Using it like this - `{{getDefaultIfNull(performance.OneMonthBack)}}`

Comment: @RehbanKhatri would be it a method or a pipe?

Comment: A method in component. But you can also create a custom pipe

Comment: check <td>{{performance.country_id ? performance.country_id : 2}}</td>

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**UPDATED on 03.01.2020**

There are multiple ways.

Using only the template:

1. use empty array (or maybe some fallback array) if its undefined or null..:

```html
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let performance of (performances || [])">
      <td>{{ performance.id }}</td>
      ...
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

2. check it inline and use a default value:

```html
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let performance of performances">
      <td>{{ performance?.id || 1337 }}</td>
      ...
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

3. you could use *ngIf:

```html
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let performance of performances">
      <td *ngIf="performance?.id; else elsePerfId">{{ performance.id }}</td>
      <ng-template #elsePerfId>
        <td>default</td>
      </ng-template>
      ...
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

4. using a pipe and returning a default value:

```html
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let performance of (performances | defaultValueIfNullPipe)">
      <td>{{ performance.id }}</td>
      ...
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Using Component..

You could also take care that there are no invalid values:

```js
getFunds(){
    this._service.getData().then(
        performances => this.performances = performances || [] /* empty array or default value here */
    );
}
```

Answer (score 29):

**Nevermind - this checks if the array is null, not elements within the array.**

Instead of the custom pipe, you could just do a null check right in the `*ngFor`, I think it's pretty readable. You're just providing an empty array if `performances` is null:

```
<tr *ngFor="let performance of (performances ? performances : [])">
```

Comment: This would check if the array itself is null, but I'm pretty sure they want to check individual elements within the array.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery should I delete this answer? I don't know the protocol for this.

Comment: great answer. some of us were actually looking for this. thanks.

Comment: Brilliant!!! If iterating over object with array property do: <tr *ngFor="let performance of (obj?.performances ? obj?.performances : [])">

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way - use initialization:

```
  projects: ProjectData[] = [];
  services: ServiceData[] = [];
  members: MemberData[] = [];
```

This will make `*ngFor` iterate zero times.

Answer (score -2):

Use safe navigation operator(?) along with || operator. Lesser code than all above solutions.

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let performance of performances">
      <td>{{performance?.id || : 1234}}</td>
      ...
    </tr>
</tbody>
```